# Spivak - a function cannot approach two different limits near a, why two different numbers $\varepsilon_1$ and $\varepsilon_2$ are not used?

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

I'm trying to understand Spivak's proof of the theorem

> A function cannot approach two different limits near $a$. In other words, if $f$ approaches $l$ near $a$, and $f$ approaches $m$ near $a$, then $l=m$.

First thing he rewrites the hypothesis according to the definition:

$0<|x-a|<\delta_1 \rightarrow |f(x)-l|<\varepsilon$

$0<|x-a|<\delta_2 \rightarrow |f(x)-m|<\varepsilon$

He says

> We have had to use two numbers $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$, since there's no guarantee that the $\delta$ which works in one definition will work in the other.

Why does he not use two different numbers $\varepsilon_1$ and $\varepsilon_2$? Such that

$0<|x-a|<\delta_1 \rightarrow |f(x)-l|<\varepsilon_1$

$0<|x-a|<\delta_2 \rightarrow |f(x)-m|<\varepsilon_2$

It's two different limits, why does he use the same $\varepsilon$ for both?

Comment: In each case $\epsilon$ is something the writer can $\textit {choose}$.  The various $\delta's $ are then fixed by the function and the writer has no control over them (though properties of the function at least imply that they exist).  There is no reason not to choose the same $\epsilon$ in each case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because he can and wants to.

He uses the following logical rule: if you assume $\forall x,\ P(x)$, you can use $P(y)$ for any $y$. So, if you assume $\forall x,\ P_1(x)$ and $\forall x,\ P_2(x)$, you can assume $P_1(x)$ and $P_2(x)$ for any $x$.

However, if you assume $\exists x,\ Q(x)$, you can name something by a letter, say $y$, that you haven't used before, and assume $Q(y)$. Therefore, if you assume $\exists x,\ Q_1(x)$ and $\exists x,\ Q_2(x)$, all you can do is choose two unused letters, say, $y_1$ and $y_2$, and assume $Q_1(y_1)$ and $Q_2(y_2)$.

Comment: I somehow missed that $\varepsilon$ is all numbers $\varepsilon>0$‍♂️ Thank you.

Comment: This sentence doesn't make sense. How could $\epsilon$ be all numbers?

Comment: What I wrote in the above comment indeed doesn't make sense, but I meant that $\varepsilon$ is a particular by arbitrarily chosen positive real number.